# Interpreting Multinomial Regression output using R nnet

Tags: r, regression, interpretation

I am looking for some advice on how to interpret and report my multinomial regression analysis.  I cannot find a clear answer online

I have conducted a multinomial regression. I have a dataset with an outcome variable (verdict: guilty, not guilty and not proven) and two predictor variables (complexity: standard and scientific --> called standardsci as a variable) and (timing: before and after --> called afterbef as a variable)

I have used the relevel function to select a baseline category for my outcome variables. (verdictoutputvariable)

The model:[image]

I then used the Z tests to get p values: [image]

I am just unsure how to interpret these results? I am writing my dissertation and this is just one predictor variable. Any advice on how to actually interpret these would be amazing!

Comment: Writing an answer below now, but as a side note - you may actually want to look into log-linear models given you have three categorical variables. The results they produce are a little more interpretable in my opinion. See this link: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiUqu_iiaXiAhUm7XMBHVztAiMQFjAHegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdata.library.virginia.edu%2Fan-introduction-to-loglinear-models%2F&usg=AOvVaw06FchZb1Zl-ALVuyUE3Vzv

Comment: Scratch that - someone else wrote a better answer than I could here: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/